# How to stop delay every certain period of time (like 1 hour) in Anylogic?

Tags: java, simulation, helper, anylogic

I'm a beginner and I want to simulate the process of a holiday event through a DES model. There is a Delay with a capacity of 50 used to indicate that the audience is watching the show. I want to set this Delay to stop once every 1 hour, and all agents in the Delay should leave after the end of one hour. But I don’t know how to set it up to achieve this goal, and I’m not sure where and how to put the code. Could somebody help me? Thank you very much!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQTs5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTFkC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your Delay block to free agents "until stopDelay is called":
   [image]
2. Create a cyclic event that triggers every hour.
3. In the event action code, you can write `delay.stopDelayForAll()`
   [image]

Comment: please upvote if the reply was helpful, helps future users with similar problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote